# How to generalize transversality condition?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

Consider the system

$$ \dot{x} = f(x,y)$$
$$\dot{y} = g(x,y)$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, with the following properties:

1. The y-hyperplane consists of equilibria, $f(0,y) = g(0,y) \equiv 0$.
2. The y-plane loses normal hyperbolicity at a point $y^*$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,y^*)=0$.
3. This loss of normal hyperbolicity is caused by the transverse eigenvalue crossing zero transversally, $\nabla_y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,y^*) \neq 0$.

Now, I want to generalize these conditions to the case $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Conditions 1 and 2 are straightforward, but I'm having trouble figuring out condition 3 because now $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,y^*)$ is not a scalar but a matrix.

How could I generalize condition 3 for the $N$-dimensional case?

Comment: It seems that maybe in this case you should apply something like [Routh-Hurwitz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion) to matrix $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,y^*)$? This would show if there are any eigenvalues of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,y^*)$ with zero real part. Is that what you want?

Comment: Condition 2 already shows that there exists an eigenvalue with zero real part at (0,y*). What condition 3 does is to say that the directional derivative at the zero-eigenvalue, tangential to the plane of equilibria, is non-zero. My idea was that maybe I could redefine this condition for the case of a manifold of equilibria, in terms of the directional derivative of the algebraic equation for the zero-eigenvalue. However, I would like to know if there is an equivalent condition in terms of some properties of the Jacobian.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've overlooked a bit what condition you were generalizing. Have no idea at the moment what could be a reasonable generalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with way to generalize the transversality condition by borrowing ideas from Theorem 3.4.1 in [Guckenheimer and Holmes](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387908199). Basically, the transversality condition is the same transversality condition required for a transcritical bifurcation ($\partial^2 f /\partial \mu \partial x (v)$ where $v$ is the right eigenvector of the zero eigenvalue of the Jacobian at $(0,y^*)$) with $ \mu = y$ as the bifurcation parameter. The problem here is that we have $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ so the dimensions don't work. However, we can extend the condition to higher dimensions by projecting the 3-tensor $\partial^2 f /\partial \mu \partial x$ onto both the right $v$ and the left $w^T$ eigenvectors of the zero eigenvalue (see SN3 in Theorem 3.4.1):

$$w^T \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} (v,v)$$

to make it easier to compute, we can rewrite the transversality condition as $w^T u$ where $u \in \mathbb{R}^N$ $N$ has entries
$$u_i = v^T \frac{\partial r_i^T}{\partial y} v,$$
where $\partial r_i^T/\partial x$ is an $N \times N$ matrix and $r_i$ is the $i$-th row of $\partial f /\partial x$ at the bifurcation point.